# How to run only the test cases added in a test suite and not all the test cases available in the class?

Tags: python, python-unittest, test-suite

I have written a Test Suite.

myTestsuite.py

```
import unittest
from myTestCase2 import MyTestCase2
from prime_num_validation import Prime_Num_Validation

def my_test_suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(MyTestCase2('test_greaterCheck2'))
    #To add only test case: test_greaterCheck2 from the MyTestCase2 class
    suite.addTest(Prime_Num_Validation('test_prime_check'))
    #To add only test case: test_prime_check from the MyTestCase2 class
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(my_test_suite())
```

Now when I run this using command line with: `python -m unittest -v myTestsuite`, It runs all the test cases from the `MyTestCase2` class, which actually has 3 TC's, but we added only one out of 3 in our suite.

How should we avoid invoking all test case and executing only those which are present in the suite.

When I run this using Pycharm editor, 
it again executes all the test cases from `MyTestCase2`.

Comment: You can skip the unit test, if you don't want to run that.

Comment: Have a look at pytest, it is so much more convenient

Comment: @MaxNoe, we need to use unittest and not pytest due to some constraints.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer we need to use unittest framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the marker on top of your unit test, something call xfail that will skip the test.

**for example,**

Below example skip `test_function3()`

```
import sys

def test_function1():

def test_function2():

@pytest.mark.skipif(sys.version_info < (3,3),
                    reason="requires python3.3")
def test_function3():
```

For reference please go through this site, you will find more information py.test [skipif](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/skipping.html)

---

the link I provided above has example of using xfail marker also.

You can use the xfail marker or create your own custom marker also. xfail is to indicate that you expect a test to fail.

You can run xfail test using following command.

```
pytest --runxfail
```

As with `skipif` you can also mark your expectation of a failure on a particular 
platform:

**Example**

```
import pytest
xfail = pytest.mark.xfail

@xfail
def test_func1():
    assert 0

@xfail(run=False)
def test_func2():
    assert 0
```

Comment: XFail: mark test functions as expected to fail. xfail marker also can be used but its main purpose is to use to expected failure.

Comment: Lethal, we don't need any marker in this, as we already are adding selective test cases in suite, it would become redundant to use marker.

Comment: or else you can create the custom marker if you xfail and skipif is redundant. have look at this site: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html

Comment: Lethal, we don't need markers for this case of test suite wherein addition of test cases are taken selectively.
It's only the execution which needs to be taken care of.
the answer u posted is great but sorry it won't help for this.

Comment: Ur post is all about skipping some test cases, we don't need to do it explicitly using markers, pls understand the question it has already taken care of selecting test cases using addTest() method.

Answer (score 0):

I also assumed that running ***python -m unittest -v myTestsuite*** would execute just the test cases in the defined test suites. Calling the ***myTestsuite.py*** test module directly (i.e., not passing module as a parameter to the unittest library module), however, should produce the result you are after. Try running the following:

```
python myTestsuite
```

NOTE: You will need to pass the "verbosity=1" argument to the TextTestRunner function instead of using "-v" on command line (or modify myTestsuite.py to take a "-v" parameter and pass that to TextTestRunner)